# Rails best practice for deployment to make sure everything is ready

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have deployed a rails project on a new server but it got many errors in use since we haven't tested is carefully, actually it's too rush for this release. So I would like to ask with your experience for best practice about how to avoid the basic environment setup issue in deployment, mainly I met the following issues:

1. we use [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) in the system, but I forgot to initialize workers for it so that the background job is failed but I haven't got any exception until I realize to check its status.
2. missing some required 3rd library - we use [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) to generate pdf with html, it raise exception when the user use it, that's weird.
3. missing 3rd file - we are using /usr/share/dict/words, but it's missing in AWS, need to install it manually, got exception to realize it.

is there any idea to help me find a best way to avoid these case to happen again? add automated test then run it after deployed? add validation to config/application.rb raise exception if environment is not ready?

Any suggestions might be help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, are you writing tests? Writing tests around every piece of code you write ensures that you can keep your finger on the pulse of your app's stability when you're going to run a deploy.

A CI server is a Continuous Integration client that will run your testing suite. You can integrate these services with your app per commit to ensure that every commit you and your team produces will work against the code.

So in order to guarantee my deploy is "non-controversial", I see that all these tests are running fine before I deploy.

---

You can also use Capistrano to write lists of things that need to be accomplished on deploys, like initializations ( in your case, delayed_job ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I'm not the system admin in this deployment, just a developer, I write tests and they will catch these issues if deployer can run the tests when he think it's ready, not only just view the page.

Comment: What I'm thinking is the best way to co-work with the deployer, to ask him to run the tests on server? or stop him to start the server when the environment is not ready and so on.

Comment: @Zernel Yah for sure, ensure that anyone doing the deploy has run all the tests and is sticking to a specific pattern of deployment. This will guarantee you that your processes are running, and your code is functional.